# How do I use R to scrape website data that’s generated by js/ajax techniques?

Tags: javascript, r, v8, rvest, httr

I am currently attempting to scrape polling center data from the official website of the 2018 Afghanistan election. I need to be able to retrieve data from each of the several thousand individual polling centers that were used during the election.

This is the page for results from the poll centers in Kabul province: http://www.iec.org.af/results_2018/en/home/finalresult_by_pc/1

I previously scraped data from Afghanistan's 2010 election site by using Chrome’s dev tools to find the URLs for the html pages that the site was loading via javascript. This allowed me to grab the information I needed using a straightforward rvest loop. The 2018 website uses Ajax techniques, which I am unfamiliar with, and I can’t figure out how to retrieve the data I need from it.

Further complicating things, each polling center only lists the total number of votes cast for the candidates who appear on a single results page, and some of the districts have hundreds of candidates (ex: [this screenshot of a polling station's 17th page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32KLP.jpg), which lists a total of four votes cast). In order to get the data that I need, I’ll need to be able to retrieve the totals from each page so that I can add them together.

Any insights into how to accomplish this project would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Rcrawler https://github.com/salimk/Rcrawler

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've taken  a look at it, and unfortunately can't get the vBrowser argument (which is necessary for javascript) to work without receiving an "Error in "browser:" + i : non-numeric argument to binary operator" message.